# How to plot trapezoidal intuitionistic fuzzy number graph in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

If my function is as below, then how to draw the graph of it in latex? I need to have the graph of both the functions in one graph.[image]

Comment: If the problem is solved then please accept/upvote the provided answers.

Answer (score 1):

In my thesis I use something like this for representing my fuzzy membership functions.  You can easily adapt this code on you case. For this you need to change the path using for representing the functions and their fill and change the labels of the X axis.

This is the result of this code (compiled with lualatex) :
[image: trapezoidal fuzzy functions]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-1}{RGB}{178,24,43}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-2}{RGB}{214,96,77}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-3}{RGB}{244,165,130}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-4}{RGB}{253,219,199}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-5}{RGB}{247,247,247}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-6}{RGB}{209,229,240}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-7}{RGB}{146,197,222}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-8}{RGB}{67,147,195}
\definecolor{RdBu-9-9}{RGB}{33,102,172}


\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

% Styles
\tikzset{%
  ffa/.style={%
    pattern=north west lines,
    pattern color=RdBu-9-2, 
    draw=none
  },
  ffa2/.style={%
    pattern=north east lines,
    pattern color=RdBu-9-8, 
    draw=none
  },
  ffa_fade/.style={%
    ffa, 
    path fading=east
  },
  ffa_fade_m/.style={%
    ffa, 
    path fading=west
  },
  ffa2_fade/.style={%
    ffa2, 
    path fading=east
  },
  ffa2_fade_m/.style={%
    ffa2, 
    path fading=west
  },
  ffc/.style={%
    draw=RdBu-9-1, 
    line width=1
  },
  ffc2/.style={%
    draw=RdBu-9-9, 
    line width=1
  },
  % Rendu ligne transparente sans apparition des patterns en dessous
  ffc_fade/.style={%
    ffc, 
    draw=white, 
    postaction={%
      draw=RdBu-9-1, 
      path fading=east
    }
  },
  ffc_fade_m/.style={%
    ffc, 
    draw=white, 
    postaction={%
      draw=RdBu-9-1, 
      path fading=west
    }
  },
  ffc2_fade/.style={%
    ffc2, 
    draw=white, 
    postaction={%
      draw=RdBu-9-9, 
      path fading=east
    }
  },
  ffc2_fade_m/.style={%
    ffc2, 
    draw=white, 
    postaction={%
      draw=RdBu-9-9, 
      path fading=west
    }
  }
}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\decalageX{-.2}
  \def\decalageY{-.2}

  % functions
  \begin{scope}[transparency group]
    \begin{scope}
      \path[ffa]  (3,0) -- (3.5, 2) -- (5.5,2) -- (6,0) -- cycle;
      \path[ffa2]  (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (3,2) -- (3.5, 0) -- (5.5,0) --
      (6,2) --(9,2) -- (9,0) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \path[ffc] (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3.5, 2) --(5.5,2) -- (6,0) -- (9,0) ;
      \path[ffc2] (0,2) -- (3,2) -- (3.5, 0) -- (5.5,0) -- (6,2) -- (9,2) ;
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  % 
  % Axis
  \begin{scope}
    % Axis X
    \begin{scope}
      % Draw axis 
      \draw[|-|] (0, \decalageX) --++ (9, 0) coordinate (x axis);
      % Add gradiations with a loop
      % You can add the labels in the {}, like 2.5/{32}
      \foreach \n/\t in {0.5/{},1.5/{},2.5/{},3.5/{},4.5/{},5.5/{},6.5/{},7.5/{},8.5/{}}
      {
        % Graduation
        \draw[-] (\n, \decalageX - .05) --++ (0, .1);
        % Graduation label
        \node[below, font=\footnotesize] at (\n, \decalageX - .05) {\t};
      }
      % label of axis
      \node[below left, xshift=-.4cm, yshift=-.1cm, font=\small] at (x
      axis) {\itshape x value};
    \end{scope}
    % Axis Y
    \begin{scope}
      \draw[-] (\decalageY ,0) --++ (0, 2) coordinate (y axis);
      % Graduations
      \foreach \n/\t in {0/{0},2/{1}}
      {
        \draw[-] (\decalageY -.05, \n) --++ (.1, 0);
        \node[left, font=\footnotesize] at (\decalageY -.05, \n) {\t};
      }
      % Label
      \node[above] at (y axis) {$\mu$};
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    % B1
    \draw[ffc,line width=.5] (3,\decalageY) -- (3,0);
    \draw[fill, RdBu-9-1] (3,\decalageY) circle (2pt);
    \draw[fill, RdBu-9-1] (3,0) circle (2pt);
    \node[below] at (3,\decalageY) {\(b1\)};
    % B2
    \draw[ffc,line width=.5] (3.5,\decalageY) -- (3.5,2);
    \draw[fill, RdBu-9-1] (3.5,\decalageY) circle (2pt);
    \draw[fill, RdBu-9-1] (3.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \node[above] at (3.5,2) {\(b2\)};
    % B3
    \draw[ffc,line width=.5] (5.5,\decalageY) -- (5.5,2);
    \draw[fill, RdBu-9-1] (5.5,\decalageY) circle (2pt);
    \draw[fill, RdBu-9-1] (5.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \node[above] at (5.5,2) {\(b3\)};
    % B4
    \draw[ffc,line width=.5] (6,\decalageY) -- (6,0);
    \draw[fill, RdBu-9-1] (6,\decalageY) circle (2pt);
    \draw[fill, RdBu-9-1] (6,0) circle (2pt);
    \node[below] at (6,\decalageY) {\(b4\)};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```